# Parameterized Functional Tests using TFS / Testing Center?

Tags: tfs, integration-testing

I'm trying to leverage the functionality of the TFS Test Case, which allows a user to add parameters to a test case.  However, when I set up a plain vanilla Unit Test (which will become my functional / integration test), and use the Insert Parameter feature, I just don't seem to be able to access the parameter data.  From the little I can find, it seems as if this parameterization is only for coded UI tests.

While it's possible for me to write a data driven unit test with the [DataSource] attribute on the test, this would mean a separate place to manage the data for the testing, potentially a new UI, etc.  Not terrible but not optimal.  What would be ideal is to manage everything through Testing Center but I cannot for the life of me find a description of how to get at that data inside the unit test.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either I didn't understand your question or maybe you answered it yourself :-). Let me explain:

Both Unit Tests and Coded UI Tests (in fact, most MSTest-based tests) leverage the same [DataSource] infrastructure. That way, tests can be parameterized without the need of embedding the parameter data in the test itself.

VS 2005 and VS 2008 basically offered databases (text, XML or relational ones) as valid test data sources. VS 2010 (and Microsoft Test Manager) introduced a new kind of data source: a "Test Case Data Source", which is automatically inserted in a Coded UI test generated from a test case recording.

But nothing prevents you from doing the same to your own unit tests. I think the workflow below could work for you:

1. Create a test case in MTM;
2. Add your parameters and data rows;
3. Save your test case. Take note of the work item ID (you're gonna need it);
4. Create your unit test and add the following attribute to the method header:

   ```
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://my-tfs-server:8080/tfs/my-collection;My-Team-Project", "WI#", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
   ```
5. In the attribute above, replace **WI#** with the work item id from #3;
6. (Optional) In Visual Studio, go to the Test menu and click Windows | Test View. Select the unit test you just created, right-click it and "Associate Test to Test Case". Point to the same test case work item created in #3 and now you turned your manual test case in a automated test case. NOTE: When you automate a test you can no longer run it manually from MTM. You need Lab Management (and an environment configured as being able to run automated tests) in order to schedule and run an automated test case.